# MongoDB finding the document with more fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, sql-like

Is it possible to obtain, from a collection, the document with the highest amount of fields?

[image: Collection]

In this case, the returned value should be the second document or just 18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation pipeline with `$objectToArray` stage starting from `3.4.4` version to convert all top key & value pair into document arrays followed by `$group` to find the `$max` with `$size` on keys.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        arrayofkeyvalue: {
            $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        max: {
            $max: {
                $size: "$arrayofkeyvalue.k"
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: I tried your solution. The result is: { "_id" : null, "max" : 5 }
Is there a way to get the _id of the document so we can get the list of the fields?
I'm trying to create a C# model for each collection. That's why I need the document having most fields.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is no direct way in mongo to find the number of keys in a document.

Here is what you can do -

```
PRIMARY> var count = 0;
PRIMARY> var temp = 0;
PRIMARY> db.sample.find().forEach( function(d) { for(f in d) { temp++; }if(temp>count){count=temp;temp=0} });
PRIMARY> count;
```

I would suggest though keep a count field in each document which contains number of keys and use it. Update it whenever a new key is added to existing document, you may index on that field for search.